# How to display data in a graph, where one attribute has 90% data and others attributes have significantly lower data

Tags: excel, graph

I need your help to understand best graphs to display data in a graph. We received IOT data, and for one activity we received 90% in a time frame, and other activities we received significantly lower data.

What is the best way to display all data in the graph, so that it can understood easily.

attribute1(90%)
attribute2(2%)
attribute3(2%)
attribute4(2%)

I tried to use line chart to display data, but data on the line chart does not looks good. As attribute1 has a lot of data and other data does not fit(or cannot see) in the graph

Comment: Excel has many chart options - cycle through them and select the one shows off the data, or the interesting part, to best advantage. However, you should at least understand your data, perhaps this may help: https://eazybi.com/blog/data-visualization-and-chart-types

Answer (score 1):

There is no "right" answer to this question as it depends on:

1. the count of attributes > 1
2. the meaning of measurements
3. the importance of attribute1
4. whether attribute1's current value of 90% is out of the ordinary
5. what is the comparison you're trying to make?
6. do you need to show attribute1 at all?

That said, in the spirit of community, some things to consider are:

If you only have a few attributes other than the big one, a pie chart might suffice (despite what the anti-pie-chart crowd might say):

[image]

If there are too many attributes, it won't help:

[image]

If it's always 90% of the total, and that face could be considered not interesting, you could consider not showing attribute1 at all:

[image]

You could calculate each attribute's deviation from past values, or their deviation from the mean, or if the attributes are groupable, you could group them to make them stand out more significantly:

[image]

This could go on and on.

Ultimately, I recommend you get laser-focused on the message you are trying to convey with your data and then process and visualize your data to that end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use what is called a pareto chart. It's basic aim is to <*highlight the biggest factors in a data set>*
[https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/create-a-pareto-chart-a1512496-6dba-4743-9ab1-df5012972856#:~:text=Click%20Insert%20%3E%20Insert%20Statistic%20Chart,Recommended%20Charts%20%3E%20All%20Charts%20tab](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/create-a-pareto-chart-a1512496-6dba-4743-9ab1-df5012972856#:%7E:text=Click%20Insert%20%3E%20Insert%20Statistic%20Chart,Recommended%20Charts%20%3E%20All%20Charts%20tab).